# Is it correct to use extensionality axiom in an algebraic theory? Is "extensionality theory" appropriate name for the identity theory plus this axiom?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

There is something about extensionality axiom which makes debatable its use in any theory, not only in an algebraic one -- this law looks more like a definition than a statement when written like this:

$\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y)     \leftrightarrow x = y$

It might be recommendable to use a form of this law which (only) looks like a weaker statement like this:

$\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y)     \rightarrow x = y$,

but since the inverse is  deducible, for the purposes of this question, I used the first form.

The extensionality axiom never caused me logical discomfort of this kind when I dealt with regular set theories, but now I am intested in algebraization of set theory and I got a feeling that this statement will create many problems in algebraization. This is why I asked the question about correctness of extensionality axiom specifically in an *algebraic* set theory. However, I started now having some logical discomfort with its presence in *formalized* regular set theories (informally everything that is understood is acceptable). Here is another question associated with those asked in title:

*Is it acceptible to use hidden or obvious definitions in a formal theory, and how one can detect which statements are hidden definitions?*

A question about a problem which does not distract with superfluous information has more chances to get an answer. This is why I referred in my question to a theory with only this axiom and the axioms of equality (identity).

This theory showcases a certain kind of logical difficulty and I would like in my communication with students to reference this difficulty by using a name. That is why I asked weather the name ``extensionality theory'' sounds appropriate (i.e. it does not refer to another phenomenon, or something like this).

**ADDITION:** The extensionality axiom contains the symbol "$\in$"  of a relation and it cannot be used as it is in an algbraic set theory, but my question implied that this symbol is expressed through adjunction operation in the algebraic theory. The adjunction operation "$\rhd$" is defined like this $x \rhd y \rightleftharpoons x \cup \{ y\}$. Therefore, $x \in y \rightleftharpoons (y \rhd x = y)$. Thus, one can substitute the left hand expression  with the right hand expression in the extensionality axiom, and this will contain no symbol of relation in its new form.

Comment: Just to double check, are you aware of https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS and https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+set+theory ?

Comment: I'm not sure that the membership relation makes sense in an algebraic theory (in the sense of https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+theory), since it is not an equation, but a _relation_.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: I am aware of the "algebraic set theory" presented in terms of category theory. This theory uses infinitary operations in a signature that is a proper class. However, I am interested in algebraization in terms of universal algebra, that is an algebraization where only finitary operations are used and an axiomatic theory of sets in presented.

Comment: @DavidRoberts The membership relation should not be present in an algebraic theory . My question was intended to refer to the "algebraic image" of this axiom. The membership relation can be easily expressed by a formula through the adjunction operation like this is explained in my other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306165/what-is-algebraic-theory-in-the-wide-sense.

Comment: ETCS is definitely an "algebraic" set theory that is finitely presented, in first-order logic.

Comment: I do not see what you are talking about, regarding the "adjunction operation" unfortunately. You should edit this in to the question here, to make it self-contained.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Please notice my Addition in reply to your last comment

Comment: @DavidRoberts My knowledge of algebraic theory does not allow me to immediately reply to  your remark about ETCS. But it seems that a remark to another question of mine says that ETCS is not algebraic. See my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306165/what-is-algebraic-theory-in-the-wide-sense?noredirect=1#comment8981933_4306165.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "algebraic". As far as I'm concerned algebraic theories have free models, and set theory doesn't, so it can't be turned into an algebraic theory.

Comment: I am not sure what is "algebraic"  and this is why I also asked this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306165/what-is-algebraic-theory-in-the-wide-sense, However, I would like to hear any answer to this question with "algebraic" treated in the largest sense.

Comment: "Algebraic" can mean models for an operad, or a PROP, or a PRO, or a monad, or... Category theorists keep making new ways for things to be algebraic. I'm afraid I don't understand enough to be able to answer your question.